# How to quickly test if postgres database is accessible?

Tags: postgresql

I whished there were a tool like ping for databases? I just want to ping the database and see if it is accessible from a remote server from Linux command line (bash).

I read about telnet, but I am not sure how it works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

Something like:

```
pg_isready --host=192.168.79.8 --username=test --port=5432
```

> 192.168.79.8:5432 - no response

Another solutions is telnet:

```
telnet 192.168.79.8 5432
```

Which returns:

> Trying 192.168.79.8...
> Connected to 192.168.79.8.
> Escape character is '^]'.

If the database is accessible.